# screensaver two monitors two images

Tags: macos, display, screensaver, dual-screen

I'd like to display a different image on each of my two monitors as the screensaver. The "Classic" screensaver almost does this, but it always mirrors the same image to both monitors.

A way to display a single, larger image spanned across the two screens would also work just as well for me.

Comment: as long you use the monitor mirroring how would that work

Comment: @Buscar웃: I don't. The Classic screensaver mirrors the images to both of the un-mirrored monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your screensaver to use your iPhoto library will have it display different images on each display.

If `My Photo Stream` and `Photo Library…` are not choices listed in the Source list box, you may need to rebuild your thumbnails and/or cache in iPhoto first (start iPhoto while pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>).

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: It certainly does so on my Lion 10.7.5 system.

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean. I can't find any mention of the word "iPhoto" in the screensaver config dialogs.

Comment: In 10.9 I only get the same image. @bukzor  When you select one of the Photo Themes, under the preview on the right you will see a drop down to select source. That where you go to finder your iPhoto..

Comment: @bukzor, you may need to address issues with iPhoto. See my edited answer.